# join missing rows from another table columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two tables (as DataFrames) in Python. One is as follows:

```
Country     Year    totmigrants
Afghanistan 2000    
Afghanistan 2001    
Afghanistan 2002    
Afghanistan 2003    
Afghanistan 2004    
Afghanistan 2005    
Afghanistan 2006    
Afghanistan 2007    
Afghanistan 2008    
Algeria     2000    
Algeria     2001    
Algeria     2002
...
Zimbabwe    2008
```

the other one is for each single year (9 seperate DataFrames overall 2000-2008):

```
Year=2000
---------------------------------------
Country    totmigrants  Gender  Total
Afghanistan 73           M     70
Afghanistan              F     3
Albania     11           M     5
Albania                  F     6
Algeria     52           M     44
...
Zimbabwe                 F     1
```

I want to join them together, the first table being outer join.
I had this in my mind but this only works for merging by columns:

```
new=pd.merge(table1,table2,how='left',on=['Country', 'Year'])
```

What I wanted to see is, from each data frame for each year total number of migrants, F and M occur in new columns in the first table as:

```
Country     Year    totmigrants F  M
Afghanistan 2000      73       3  70
Afghanistan 2001    table3
Afghanistan 2002    table4
Afghanistan 2003    ...
Afghanistan 2004    
Afghanistan 2005    
Afghanistan 2006    
Afghanistan 2007    
Afghanistan 2008    
Algeria     2000    52          8 44
Algeria     2001    table3      ...
Algeria     2002    table4      ...
...
Zimbabwe    2008     ...        ...
```

Is there a specific method for this merging, or what function do I need to use?

Comment: Before you merge, try groupby country and sum totalmigrants, or only select rows which have a totalmigrant integer value.

Comment: The first table does not have any useful data (unless you are not showing us all columns). Why do you need it at all?

Comment: @DYZ There are 10 more variables in that table. I can not copy paste all. Other variables are ready but only `totmigrants, F and M` are missing. I need it for running a regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to combine the data from the yearly dataframes. Let's assume that the yearly dataframes somehow have been stored in a dictionary:

```
df = {2000: ..., 2001: ..., ..., 2008: ...}
yearly = []

for N in df.keys():
    tmp = df[N].pivot('Country','Gender','Total').fillna(0).astype(int)
    tmp['Year'] = N # Store the year
    tmp['totmigrants'] = tmp['M'] + tmp['F']
    yearly.append(tmp)

df = pd.concat(yearly)
print(df)
#Gender       F   M  Year  totmigrants
#Country                              
#Afghanistan  3  70  2000           73
#Albania      6   5  2000           11
#Algeria      0  44  2000           44
#Zimbabwe     1   0  2000            1
```

Now you can merge `df` with the first dataframe using `['Country','Year']` as the keys.

Comment: this was helpful. When converting data to dataframe, I am encountering this problem: in some of tables gender rows are merged. e.g. `Afghanistan 108.0 M\nF 98\n10                                    Albania 18.0 M\nF 10\n8`

Comment: how can I separate them into two distinct rows before I can convert them into Dataframe?

Comment: This is a different question and requires it's own code and sample data.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you need the first table. I did the following, I hope it helps.

```
data2000 = np.array([['','Country','totmigrants','Gender', 'Total'],
['1','Afghanistan', 73, 'M', 70],
['2','Afghanistan', None, 'F', 3],
['3','Albania', 11, 'M', 5],
['4','Albania', None ,'F', 6]])

data2001 = np.array([['','Country','totmigrants','Gender', 'Total'],
['1','Afghanistan', 75, 'M', 60],
['2','Afghanistan', None, 'F', 15],
['3','Albania', 15, 'M', 11],
['4','Albania', None ,'F', 4]])

# and so on
datas = {'2000':data2000, '2001':data2001}
reg_dfs = []
for year,data in datas.items():
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
              index=data[1:,0],
              columns=data[0,1:])

    new=pd.merge(df,df,how='inner',on=['Country'])
    reg_df = new.query('Gender_x == "M" & Gender_y == "F"' )[['Country', 'Total_x', 'Total_y', 'totmigrants_x']]
    reg_df.columns = ['Country', 'M', 'F', 'Total']
    reg_df['Year'] = year
    reg_dfs.append(reg_df)

print(pd.concat(reg_dfs).sort(['Country']))

#       Country   M   F Total  Year
#1  Afghanistan  70   3    73  2000
#1  Afghanistan  60  15    75  2001
#5      Albania   5   6    11  2000
#5      Albania  11   4    15  2001
```